# View-bag to fill checkbox-list using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Below is my model class

```
public class InformationMissing : AbstractDBObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PatientDemographics { get; set; }
    public string InsuranceDetails { get; set; }
    public string PhysicianDetails { get; set; }
    public string Note { get; set; }
    public int personId {get;set;}
    public string status { get; set; }
    public List<CheckboxList_model> RetrievalItem { get; set; }

}
public class CheckboxList_model
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public Boolean Selected { get; set; }

}
```

below is my controller method

```
 public ActionResult Process()
    {
       List<CheckboxList_model> chkRetrieval = new List<CheckboxList_model>(){
          new CheckboxList_model{ Text="One", Value = 1 ,Selected=false},
          new CheckboxList_model{ Text="Two", Value = 2 ,Selected=false},
          new CheckboxList_model{ Text="Three", Value = 3 ,Selected=false }
          };

          ViewBag.Retrieval = chkRetrieval;
         return View();
    }
```

Below code i have tried but checkboxlist is not filling

```
       @foreach (var Retrieval in ViewBag.Retrieval)
           {

    @Html.CheckBoxFor(Retrieval.Selected, new { @class = "flat" })

    @Html.DisplayFor(Retrieval.Text)

    @Html.HiddenFor(Retrieval.Value)

           }
```

From below foraech able to see text value but above checkboxlist is not filling

```
    @foreach (var Retrieval in ViewBag.Retrieval)
            {
                 <p>
    @Retrieval.Text </p>

                    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code work for me using Viewbag

```
 @foreach (var names in ViewBag.Retrieval)
            {
                var checkBoxId = "chk" + names.Value;
                var tdId = "td" + names.Value;
                <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="20px">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="@checkBoxId" class="chkclass" value="@names.Value" />
                        </td>
                        <td id="@tdId" width="100px">
                            @names.Text
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to unbox the **ViewBag.Retrieval** in the actual model list in your view like below.

### UnBoxing In Your View

```
@{
    var checkboxList = (List<CheckboxList_model>)ViewBag.Retrieval
 }
```

### Iterating checkbox list

```
@foreach (var Retrieval in checkboxList)
{
    <p>@Retrieval.Text </p>
}
```

Comment: where is checkboxlist in the view. @Sufyan Yaqoob

Comment: I have unboxed the ViewBag.Retrieval in a new variable checkboxList.

Comment: not working bro your code. @Sufyan Yaqoob

Comment: but you need to fill into checkboxlist where you are filling in the above code. @Sufyan Yaqoob

Comment: foreach (var Retrieval in checkboxList)
{
    <p>@Retrieval.Text </p>
} this is working but checkboxlist code is not working. @Sufyan Yaqoob